# Custom message error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
why when I use a custm message and I try to see it with che command line "$gztopic echo [message]" I return this error message: "Unable to get message type for topic [message]?"

If I try to see the message with the GUI the error message is: "Unable to parse message of type [message_type]"

How I need to configure gazebo to understand my custom message?

thanks for all the answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4850/custom-message-error/) by [GuidoG](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/553/guidog/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In order to understand your custom message type, `gztopic` and the Gazebo gui would need to be recompiled and linked with the protobuf headers from your custom message type. You can write your own tools the publish and subscribe to custom messages (see [the tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/custom_messages)), but the pre-compiled Gazebo tools won't be able to parse them.

Unless, of coure, you did something fancy with [self-describing messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description), but that's probably a lot of effort.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuidoG](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/553/guidog/) on 2013-10-30**:
In few words it's nota automatic the parse of a custom message, like in ROS. Thanks for your answer!

**Comment by [GuidoG](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/553/guidog/) on 2013-10-30**:
In few words it's nota automatic the parse of a custom message, like in ROS.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-30**:
Could please mark the answer as correct using the check button?

**Comment by [AlexandreB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2369/alexandreb/) on 2017-07-14**:
I would love to have more information on to process to get Gazebo to compiler my custom message. Im trying to read the custom messages of https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo in Gazebo Gui.

**Comment by [Nuno Marques](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4653/nuno-marques/) on 2018-12-03**:
@scpeters does Gazebo 9 currently supports self-describing messages? For using them, is there anything we need to be aware on the Gazebo side? The idea is not having to recompile Gazebo but rather use custom plugins with custom messages that could use the Gazebo tools to parse them (including echoing using `gztopic -e <topic>`